# Change transition duration during loop with requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm trying to change the transition duration in-between the steps of a `setTimeout` loop.

When the button *centre* is clicked, `setView` changes the position of `content` so that the `inner` div remains in the centre of the screen. It uses a `forEach` loop to change the centring using an array of `inner` divs.

I'd like the transition between the change from *alpha inner* to *bravo inner* to take `1s`, but once it gets there the transition should be `0s` so that is no lag with the centring.

[Here's a codepen, then built in is getting an error.](https://codepen.io/sansSpoon/pen/NBjvGR)

I'm using vanilla ES6.

```js
const content = document.querySelector('.content');
let frame;

function getBounds(div) {
 const element = document.getElementById(div);
 const body = element.children[0];
 const {
  x, y, width, height,
 } = body.getBoundingClientRect();
 return box = {
  element, body, x: Math.round(x), y: Math.round(y), width, height,
 };

}

function setView(div) {
 const centerW = window.innerWidth / 2;
 const centerH = window.innerHeight / 2;
 const { left, top } = content.getBoundingClientRect();
 content.style.left = `${(centerW + left) - (div.x + div.width / 2)}px`;
 content.style.top = `${(centerH + top) - (div.y + div.height / 2)}px`;
}

function centreDiv(string) {
 const outers = string.split(' ');
 
 outers.forEach(function(outer, index) {
  setTimeout(function() {
   content.style.transition = 'all 0s linear'; // this works

   if (frame) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(frame);
   }

   function tick(now) {
    setView(getBounds(outer));
    frame = requestAnimationFrame((timestamp) => tick(timestamp, outer));
   }

   frame = requestAnimationFrame((timestamp) => tick(timestamp, outer));
  },
  5000 * index);

  content.style.transition = 'all 1s linear'; // this isn't working
 });

}

document.getElementById('centre').onclick = () => centreDiv(centreText.value.toLowerCase());
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
html,body,div,span {padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0;}
.controls {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1000;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: white;
}

.content {
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 width: 100vw;
 height:100vh;
 background-color: rgb(138,141,143);
 transition: all 0s linear;
}

.centre {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 width: 5px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color: white;
}

.outer {
 position: absolute;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: flex-end;
}

.inner {
 display: block;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: rgb(37,40,42);
}

.animate {
 animation: spin infinite linear;
}

#alpha {
 width: 80%;
 height: 80%;
 background-color: rgb(255,205,0);
 animation-duration: 10s;
}

#bravo {
 width: 30%;
 height: 30%;
 background-color: rgb(242,169,0);
 animation-duration: 5s;
}

@keyframes spin {
 100% {
  transform: rotateZ(360deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
 centre: <input id="centreText" type="text" value="alpha bravo"/><button type="button" id="centre">centre</button>
</div>
<div class="content">
 <div id="alpha" class="animate outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="bravo" class="animate outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="centre"></div>
</div>
```